# Unable to update using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have written the following code to update VoterStatus of my table

```
var vtrs = (from k in db.Voters
            where k.VoterID.Equals(vid)
            select k);
if (vtrs != null)
{
    foreach (Voters vx in vtrs)
    {
        vx.VoterID = vid;
        vx.VoterStatus = 3;
    }
    db.Voters.InsertOnSubmit(voter);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Here VoterID is the primary key of Voters table. It is raising an `SqlException`:

> Unable to insert null in VoterID in dbo.Voters

I have also tried

```
var vtrs = (from k in db.Voters
            where k.VoterID.Equals(vid)
            select k);
if (vtrs != null)
{
    foreach (Voters vx in vtrs)
    {
        vx.VoterStatus = 3;
    }
    db.Voters.InsertOnSubmit(voter);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: What is `voter` in `db.Voters.InsertOnSubmit(voter);`?

Comment: Side note: `vtrs` will never be `null`. Sure it might be empty, but not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var vtrs = (from k in db.Voters
                       where k.VoterID.Equals(vid)
                       select k);
        if (vtrs != null)
        {
            foreach (Voters vx in vtrs)
            {
                vx.VoterID = vid;
                vx.VoterStatus = 3;
            }
            db.Voters.InsertOnSubmit(voter);
            db.SubmitChanges();
```

In your code what is voter, it is not declared anywhere.  Try this instead

```
var vtrs = (from k in db.Voters
                       where k.VoterID.Equals(vid)
                       select k);
        if (vtrs != null)
        {
            foreach (Voters vx in vtrs)
            {

                vx.VoterStatus = 3;
                //db.Voters.InsertOnSubmit(vx); Only use this when inserting
            }

            db.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var vtrs = (from k in db.Voters
            where k.VoterID.Equals(vid)
            select k);
    if (vtrs != null)
    {
        foreach (Voters vx in vtrs)
        {

            vx.VoterStatus = 3;
        }
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your mistake:

```
var vtrs = (from k in db.Voters
                           where k.VoterID.Equals(vid)
                           select k);
            if (vtrs != null)
            {
                foreach (Voters vx in vtrs)
                {

                    vx.VoterStatus = 3;
                }
                db.Voters.InsertOnSubmit(voter); // what is voter pass here vx
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }
```

like this:

```
var vtrs = (from k in db.Voters
                               where k.VoterID.Equals(vid)
                               select k);
                if (vtrs != null)
                {
                    foreach (Voters vx in vtrs)
                    {

                        vx.VoterStatus = 3;
                    }
                    db.Voters.InsertOnSubmit(vx);
                    db.SubmitChanges();
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please remove below line, it's not needed for updating an entity,

```
db.Voters.InsertOnSubmit(voter);// also here is one typo , check your entity object name
```

[more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399339%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)